# How long can I be AFK on Fortnite before getting banned?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I want to know if like, maybe I have to use the toilet in the middle of Fortnite Battle Royale, and I go AFK for a couple minutes, how long can I stay AFK before getting perm banned?

Answer (score 26):

Fortnite relies on players reporting you for AFKing for bans. In addition, the only real mentions I can find of people being permabanned for going AFK has 3 major similarities:

1. They're repeat and serial offenders who get multiple reports for going AFK every match;
2. They weren't just AFKing for several minutes, but rather actively using macros and bots to stay online beyond the normal 2-3 minutes it takes for the inactivity to kick them out of the game;
3. They were leeching rewards and resources in Campaign mode games and not actively participating in the game.

I do not have official confirmation, but I'm fairly sure that if you aren't actively trying to avoid the AFK kick timer, going to the toilet for a minute or so in the middle of a match every once in a while won't be enough to be flagged as a serial offender. Especially in a BR match where players are less likely to flag you for AFK and more likely to just kill you.

However, if I may give you some advice, just go to the toilet BEFORE you start the match. Fortnite Battle Royale matches at most last 20 minutes. Unless you have a medical condition that has frequent urination or defecation as a symptom, it's unlikely that you have to wait so long between queueing up and the end of the game that you end up needing to go to the toilet during the match.

And if there is anything else you need to do while playing the game: if it's urgent, just leave the match (if you're in a team, tell your teammates that something IRL has come up and you need to leave). If it's not urgent, wait for the end of the match and don't queue again until you are done with the thing you need to do.

Comment: thanks. Lol I didn't want to get banned just going to the bathroom. Thank you.

Comment: @ACardboardBox If you think my answer helped you, be sure to upvote and accept it. Upvoting and accepting an answer adds extra visibility to the answer and also rewards me with reputation.

Answer (score -1):

In Stw, about twenty minutes.
Battle Royale, like 2 minutes. Enough to get your drink ;)